# Usercontrols that inherit from abstract class

Tags: c#, abstract-class, designer, windows-forms-designer

I've got a usercontrol that inherits from an abstract class. Basically looks like this.

```
class SimpleSlideView : View
{

}

public abstract class View : UserControl
{

}
```

The project compiles and runs fine. I can take the usercontrol (from the toolbox) and drag it into a form and it is displayed in the designer correctly. However, if I try and open the `SimpleSlideView` control itself in the designer I receive the following error:

> The designer must create an instance
>   of type 'Animation.View' but it cannot
>   because the type is declared as
>   abstract.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find possible solution here: [How can I get Visual Studio 2008 Windows Forms designer to render a Form that implements an abstract base class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620847/how-can-i-get-vs2008-winforms-designer-to-render-a-form-that-implements-an-abstra)